# Is there a way to have named configurations in Linux FTP command line client?

Tags: ftp

So in SSH/SFTP, you have the ~/.ssh/config file, which allows you to name your configurations. Basically it allows you to assign an alias to a configuration, which you can then use rather than having to remember the hostname.

For regular FTP, there's the ~/.netrc file, but that seems to not handle this very well. It still seems to work based on the hostname, with no way to assign an alias.

Is there any way to configure ~/.netrc, or the linux FTP client in general, to be able to alias my configurations? The whole reason for doing this is I don't want to have to remember the exact hostname every time I try and connect.

Comment: You can do it "old school" and use aliases, eg as defined in your `.bashrc`, such as `alias host1="ftp host1.full.name"`.  Now you can just type `host1`.

Answer (score 1):

`lftp` has `~/.lftprc`

You can place aliases there, for example

```
alias con-cme connect ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/
```

And this command line works:

```
lftp -e "con-cme"
```

Otherwise you could write several (nicely named) scripts which do what you want. Either simple shell scripts (`#!/bin/sh`) or even real "lftp scripts" (`#!/usr/bin/lftp -f`).

Here an example of such lftp script (You can think of it as an executable config file ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/lftp -f
set ftp:use-mdtm off
# ftp.cmegroup.com: 216.178.212.20, 208.39.78.6, ...
open 216.178.212.20
cat stc >/dev/null || exit 111
mirror --only-newer --delete --use-cache --verbose=3 \
    -X '20[0-9][0-9]/' \
    -X '.git' \
    -X '.metadata' \
    / /home/rudi/cme/ftp.cme.com
```